# How to append to the child node in JSON at every iteration using python provided new child node exists?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

### Sample

```py
template = {
    "Table": [
        {
            "level": 2,
            "value": {
                "element Name": "",
                "add Row": "False",
                "cost Type": "",
                "flag": "flag",
                "cost": "",
                "actions": "True"
            },
            "RHS": {},
            "children": [
                {
                    "level": 3,
                    "value": {
                        "element Name": "",
                        "add Row": "False",
                        "cost Type": "",
                        "cost": "",
                        "actions": "True"
                    },
                    "RHS": {},
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

> Considering the above dictionary, I want to append to the last "children" and every time loop runs it should append to the children created in previous iteration.
> Loop 1:
> "children":{
> "level": 4,
> "value": {"element Name": "",
> "add Row": "False",
> "cost Type": "",
> "cost": "",
> "actions": "True"},
> "RHS": {},
> "children":
> []
> }

---

Loop 2:

> iteration 2
> "children":{
> "level": 5,
> "value": {"element Name": "",
> "add Row": "False",
> "cost Type": "",
> "cost": "",
> "actions": "True"},
> "RHS": {},
> "children":
> []
> }

---

and so on.

My code is:

> Python code for loop

```
for _ in range(sublevels):
    number = number + 1
    child = {"level": sublevels + 2,
                     "value": {"element Name": "", "add Row": False,
                               "cost Type": "", "cost": "",
                               "actions": True}, "RHS": {}, "children": []}
    template['Table'][0]['children'].append(child)
```

---

Output:
After iteration, the JSON should look like below

```json
{
    "Table": [
        {
            "level": 2,
            "value": {
                "element Name": "",
                "add Row": "False",
                "cost Type": "",
                "flag": "flag",
                "cost": "",
                "actions": "True"
            },
            "RHS": {},
            "children": [
                {
                    "level": 3,
                    "value": {
                        "element Name": "",
                        "add Row": "False",
                        "cost Type": "",
                        "cost": "",
                        "actions": "True"
                    },
                    "RHS": {},
                    "children": [
                        [
                            {
                                "level": 4,
                                "value": {
                                    "element Name": "",
                                    "add Row": "False",
                                    "cost Type": "",
                                    "cost": "",
                                    "actions": "True"
                                },
                                "RHS": {},
                                "children": [
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "level": 5,
                                            "value": {
                                                "element Name": "",
                                                "add Row": "False",
                                                "cost Type": "",
                                                "cost": "",
                                                "actions": "True"
                                            },
                                            "RHS": {},
                                            "children": []
                                        }
                                    ]
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

```
Iteration 1: template['Table'][0]['children']
Iteration 2: template['Table'][0]['children'][0]['children']
Iteration 3: template['Table'][0]['children'][0]['children'][0]['children']
```

Comment: If you are always working with `template['Table'][0]` then what is the point of having `Table` as a list? Also, is your question how to append an item to the 'children' list or how to do it recursively(ish) for each sublevel?

Comment: I  am working on a huge json creation and need to append to template['Table'][0]['children'] in iteration 1 and then to template['Table'][0]['children'][0]['children'] and so on.

Comment: So, you're looking to change the content of the *deepest* `children` node of an object. Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928331/how-to-find-the-maximum-depth-of-a-python-dictionary-or-json-object to see if the solution could be customized to your need (the post looks for the deepest node, you would need to change it to find the deepest node with a particular name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

template = {"Table": []}
sublevels = 5

for _ in range(sublevels):
    #number = number + 1
    child = {"level": _ + 2,
                     "value": {"element Name": "", "add Row": False,
                               "cost Type": "", "cost": "",
                               "actions": True}, "RHS": {}, "children": []}

    cur_path = "[0]['children']"*_

    if _ == 0:
        template['Table'].append(child)
    else:
        exec(f"template['Table']{cur_path}.append(child)")


print(json.dumps(template, indent = 2))
```

Not the prettiest way, you should avoid using exec, but I was trying to call a JSON path from a dict, and it wasn't working so I used exec.

This works well and nests it tho..

Output I got from running this code:

```
{
  "Table": [
    {
      "level": 2,
      "value": {
        "element Name": "",
        "add Row": false,
        "cost Type": "",
        "cost": "",
        "actions": true
      },
      "RHS": {},
      "children": [
        {
          "level": 3,
          "value": {
            "element Name": "",
            "add Row": false,
            "cost Type": "",
            "cost": "",
            "actions": true
          },
          "RHS": {},
          "children": [
            {
              "level": 4,
              "value": {
                "element Name": "",
                "add Row": false,
                "cost Type": "",
                "cost": "",
                "actions": true
              },
              "RHS": {},
              "children": [
                {
                  "level": 5,
                  "value": {
                    "element Name": "",
                    "add Row": false,
                    "cost Type": "",
                    "cost": "",
                    "actions": true
                  },
                  "RHS": {},
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "level": 6,
                      "value": {
                        "element Name": "",
                        "add Row": false,
                        "cost Type": "",
                        "cost": "",
                        "actions": true
                      },
                      "RHS": {},
                      "children": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```